# Using Selenium(Java), how to select a value from a drop down list, when the drop down list element have limited identifiable attributes?

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to select a value from a drop down using Selenium and I have tried all possible methods(to the extent of my knowledge), but in vain.
Please help me find the appropriate method here.

Here is the HTML code, for reference:

```
<select name="list" onchange="this.disabled=true;if(this.options[selectedIndex].value == '')this.disabled=false;else optionselect(this);" onfocus="hint('')">
```

And, these are the methods, I tried.

Method-1:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"))).selectByVisibleText("Text*");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("list"))).selectByVisibleText("Text");
```

Method-2: (I tried to use every possible approach to identify the dropdown element by name, abs xpath, rel xpath, cssSelector etc., but nothing seeems to identify the element)

```
Select sel = new Select(element);
sel.selectByValue("Value");
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Method-3:

```
Select sel = new Select(element);
sel.selectByIndex(11);
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Method-4:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("list")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Text");
```

I'm guessing the issue in all the above methods lies in identifying the drop down element. But I'm really not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: are the select elements visbile at all times in the page source? or only once you click/hover over the select?

Comment: The select elements are visible only when you click/hover over the select.

Comment: you can try it by taking select element parent tag.

Comment: @SarithaG Can you please elaborate? I'm not getting your point.

Comment: You have posted only one tag (i.e., <select> ) of html code. Post extra html code. or else parent and super parent tag's of <select> tag. So that we can give more suggestions.

Comment: Are you able to successfully get a handle on the Select WebElement? And please can you provide either the URL or a larger sample of code for the website you are working with?

Comment: Thanks Everyone! The culprit in my code is the frame and after identifying the correct frame, I'm able to access the drop down element!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below.

```
WebElement dd= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='list']"));
Select s=new Select(dd);
s.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: I already tried a similar one in Method-3. Also, I tried adding a click method to the element (Since instance for 'Select' does not seem to have a click() method), still I'm not able to select the dropdown

Comment: yea. if you r unable to select the dropdown using select class. then yu can use         dd.click(); no  or else once you check whether that dropdown is in iframe

Comment: click() method will work for element, still you r unable to click on dropdown?

Comment: Yea! Even after using identifiers like name, abs xpath, rel xpath, cssSelector, I'm not able to click the dropdown using click() method. I'm receiving 'no such element' error whenever I try to access the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have some luck using Actions?

(use Firefox or Chrome, IE behaves weird when doing hover actions)

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement hoverElement = driver.findElement(By.name("list"));

Select sel = new Select(element);
// hover over the element
actions.
moveToElement(hoverElement).
perform();

// now maybe all of your approaches would work
// sel.selectByIndex(11);
// sel.selectByValue("Value");
// sel.selectByVisibleText("Text");

// or just find and click your desired element:
WebElement targetElement = driver.findElement(targetElementLocator);

    actions.
    moveToElement(targetElement).
    click().
    perform();
```

Comment: Thanks @drkthng for answering! I'm now to able to access the drop down element using Select method itself.